# Laravel slow select query in table 48k records

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to make purchase statistics. So in `for-each` like this:

`for ($month = 0; $month <= $maxMonth; $month++) {`

I made the following query in Laravel:

```
$mainData = DB::table('table')
    ->where('a', $id)
    ->where('b', '>', 0)
    ->where('c', '>', 0)
    ->orderBy('d', 'DESC')
    ->where('a', '>=', DB::raw('UNIX_TIMESTAMP((LAST_DAY(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL ' . intval($month) . ' MONTH))+INTERVAL 1 DAY)-INTERVAL 1 MONTH)'))
    ->where('a', '<', DB::raw('UNIX_TIMESTAMP(LAST_DAY(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL ' . intval($month) . ' MONTH))+INTERVAL 1 DAY)'))
    ->get();
```

I changed the name of rows because I do not think it's important information.
In addition, it takes 10-15 seconds to complete these 6 queries.

I think this is very slow because when I change `->get()` to -`>toSql()` and make query in phpmyadmin (with the same SQL) it took milliseconds.

Why is this Laravel database so slow?

Comment: Do you have any indexes on this database table? It might be interesting to have a composite index on `a`, `b` and `c` because you are filtering them all together. Also, don't make database queries in a loop!

Comment: a,b,c,d are an index in my database :)

Comment: `->where('a', $id)` and `->where('a', '>=', ..)` doesn't make sence

Comment: Have you tried chunk method?